# Change variable in scss variable file

Tags: wordpress, sass

I have a variable in an scss file:
$yellow: #XXXXXX

I've changed the value in the file, but I don't see changes coming. I've read that scss needs to be compiled... If this is the case, how do we compile it in a hosting (production site)? If not, what's the procedure?

Thanks

Changing the code in the text

//color variable
$yellow: #XXXXXX;

Comment: SASS requires a compiler. If you need to compile on the server, you'll need to install something that can compile it, e.g. gulp, grunt, compass, etc. Or there are many apps that you can install that will do it on your desktop, like Scout-App. The caveat is that will need all of the files that are required to compile (any imported files).

Comment: Ok, so this is the situation. I have inherited the project in production site. The project had been developed by another agency, which means I don't have the testing environment configured. What you're basically saying is that either we create this testing environment or we try to install on our server this kind of scripts that can compile scss. There's a probably not such orthodox way, which could be to override the scss rules with css and !important if needed. Is this a good idea just for a colour change?

Comment: If you will be working on this site long term, I would highly suggest you create a testing environment, or at least get all of the SCSS files from the server so you can compile them locally and just replace what's on the production server. You can certainly do `!important` (or just make a more specific selector chain) for a color change in another CSS file if you are only changing the color on a few elements - but who knows where else `$yellow` is being used in the source SCSS.